# How to play video in did select row method collectionview

Tags: ios, arrays, video, avplayer

I writing the following code in Collection view did select row but when I select the cell on that time I getting the following error [Error_Image In simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B9eT.png)

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if collectionView == faQs_collectionview
        {
            let fileURL =  videourls[indexPath.item]

            let playerviewcontroller = AVPlayerViewController()
            var playerview = AVPlayer()

            playerview = AVPlayer(url: fileURL as URL)

            playerviewcontroller.player = playerview

            self.present(playerviewcontroller, animated: true){

                playerviewcontroller.player?.play()
            }
        }else{

        }

    }
```

Comment: Check your video file url in correct format

Comment: My video format is var videourls:[URL] = [URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watchv=SXylZMZdWL4&list=PLjun4b7gSzKJNcHE6XoaGzCs1plJ9Vn_T&index=1")! as URL, URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5R3KCjjj38&list=PLjun4b7gSzKJNcHE6XoaGzCs1plJ9V")!, URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4xTtdmhv5Q&list=PLjun4b7gSzKJNcHE6XoaGzCs1plJ9V")!, URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUrmsmuNizE&list=PLjun4b7gSzKJNcHE6XoaGzCs1plJ9V")!, URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORQSS1t27Cs&index=5&list=PLjun4b7gSzKJNcHE6X")!,]

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the links you have provided, it seems you are trying to play YouTube videos in AVPlayer

AVPlayer is used to play media files, like if you have video or audio file somewhere on a server, and you provide that link to AVPlayer, it would play.
But YouTube links are not video files.

You will have to add either play them in webviews, like the following

```
class MyYTVideoPlayer: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var wv: UIWebView!
    var videoId:String
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard
            let youtubeURL = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoId)")
            else { return }
        wv.loadRequest( URLRequest(url: youtubeURL) )
    }
}
```

or implement YouTube Player from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper)

Comment: It is working properly but in simulator sound is coming but real device sound is not coming

Comment: Make sure in real device, the ringer is on, check the volume. I'l try to run the code on device, and get back to you.

Comment: Rechecked, the ringer must be on, and not on silent.